# Do signals contain data pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, signals, signals-slots

I have trouble understanding whether signals contain some data or not.
for example the signal `windowTitleChanged` contains a data of type str which needs to be passed to it's slot:

```
self.windowTitleChanged.connect(lambda x  : self.onTitle(x)) 

## or self.windowTitleChanged.connect(self.onTitle) which also automatically sends a data

def onTitle(self,k):
        print(k)
```

While some signals like `clicked` do not send data unless they are set as `checkable` (which contain a bool type data). clicking on the pushBotton in the code below does nothing (which surprisingly to me does not raise an error despite the fact that `def buttonClicked(self,pressed)` requires a `pressed` argument.

```
btn2.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)

def buttonClicked(self,pressed):
        if pressed:

            self.statusBar().showMessage("l")
```

It seems to me that some signals like `windowTitleChanged` contain a data and can be used within the slot, while some contain a None type data (like `clicked` signal).
Is what i've understood correct?

Comment: `QPushButton.clicked` will send data when emitted even though the button isn't checkable but it sends the value False which is why in your button example nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems to me that some signals like`windowTitleChanged` contain a data and can be used within the slot, while some contain a None type data (like `clicked` signal). Is what i've understood correct?

Yes, you are right. You can even see this in action by creating a custom signal.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, Qobject
class Analyzer(QObject):
    analyze_completed = pyqtSignal(bool)
```

In the above snippet if you emit the `analyze_completed` signal with a `bool` the slots that are connected to this signal will receive that `bool` as a parameter.

Comment: Then is it safe to say that every built-in signal in Qt contains a data which can be used if needed? How do i know what signal contains what data?

Comment: I don't know if *every* built-in signal contains data but I can say that it doesn't have to be. It's better to check what are the parameters you need to handle.

Comment: From [Qt docs](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html): *The signature of a signal must match the signature of the receiving slot. (In fact a slot may have a shorter signature than the signal it receives because it can ignore extra arguments.)* So it looks like you can ignore the parameters that you are not interested in, but I don't know if this is valid for PyQt.

Comment: @Asocia Yes this is valid for PyQt5. To OP: you can use the official Qt documentation to find out which signal sends what data.